# Limitation or limitations?

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural

I am confused about the following sentence:

> Despite **limitations** from a lack of funding, the study for the first time paints a picture of children prone to suicidal thought.

Isn't 'a lack of funding' singular? Then why it is 'limitation**s**' instead of 'limitation'?

Comment: a lack of funding has no impact on the countable noun limitation. Lack of funds impose limitations on an organization's activities.

Comment: In contexts like this we often pluralise the key word ***limitations, problems, difficulties,...*** even if in fact there's really only *one* limitation / problem / difficulty. It's not really relevant that ***a** lack of funding* here is singular, but I don't think the text as cited sounds very natural anyway. Personally, I'd prefer something like *Despite **being limited by** [a] lack of funds/funding,...*

Comment: Perhaps *"Despite limitations due to a lack of ..."*.